# How to make multiple incremental lists based on contents of a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Spent two hours working on this problem and I'm ready for some guidance.

I have a column of names, there are 6 different names, and they could be attached to any number of rows. I have a text string I want to appear in an adjacent column that's based on the name, and I'd like to include a number at the end of that string. The number would be a flat value that I begin with, and add 1 to it each time I add a row to the column for the names. My example doesn't show it starting at a flat value however.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nmSPVoDObosavZr21W1XphvYIQlIZvSrUqtCH86n3sQ/edit?usp=sharing

Complete: Thanks folks for the assistance. I'm leaving the google sheet up for folks who may have this question again.

Comment: If the number could end up,in double or triple digits shouldn't the number format be `PM-JB-01` or `PM-JB-001`?

Comment: Yes, that's true of course. Editing to reflect. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in F2 and fill down.

```
=TEXT(COUNTIF(D$2:D2, D2)+0, "\P\M-\"&LEFT(D2)&"\"&LEFT(REPLACE(D2, 1, FIND(" ", D2&" "), ""))&"-000")
```

To change the base starting value of the sequence, adjust the `+0` modifier.

This has a limitation of not recognizing duplicate initials (e.g. John Smith and Joe Sythe are both JS but count differently) but that could be compensated for if it became a problem.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. I used this and it worked out well, thank you. I was even able to understand enough of it to fiddle with it a smidge. I'm still a baby excel user so it'll take me some time to define how this works for myself, but in the meantime, I can proceed with work, thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

In `F2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A2="","","PM-"&LEFT(D2)&MID(D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1,1)&TEXT(COUNTIFS(B$1:B2,B2,C$1:C2,C2,D$1:D2,D2),"-000"))
```

Comment: But won't you still get the duplicate initials, just with a new number sequence? I was stating that duplicate initials could be compensated for but I should have specified that an alternate naming sequence needs to be defined so it can be used in case of duplicates. That has not been established yet.